# JasperReports: download dialog not appear

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, jasper-reports, weblogic

I have a problem with my *Java* web application (*WebLogic 10.3.5*, *Spring 3.1* and *JasperReports 5.0.1*) I want to export an *Excel* report, but at the end of operation, the download dialog not appear. In *Tomcat AS* everything works, but not in *WebLogic*.

Jsp code with export button:

```
<a title="Export" href="javascript:window.location.replace('<%=path %>/admin/export.com');">Export</a>
```

Spring MVC Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/export.com")
public ModelAndView exportAction(@ModelAttribute("model") UserModel model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
    SearchBean searchForm = model.getSearchForm();
    Map<String,Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    List<User>usersList = iReportService.getUsers(searchForm,null).getResults();
    JRDataSource JRdataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(usersList);
    parameterMap.put("datasource", JRdataSource);
    return new ModelAndView("XlsUserReport",parameterMap);
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

*fe-servlet.xml*

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/report.xml"/>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

report.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
    <bean id="XlsUserReport"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsXlsView"
        p:url="classpath:report/report/user.jrxml"
        p:reportDataKey="datasource">
        <property name="headers">
            <props>
                <prop key="Content-Disposition">
                    attachment; filename=users.xls
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In the same spring context I use two different resolver (UrlBasedViewResolver and XmlViewResolver) so maybe this can create problems. 
As I said, in *Tomcat AS*, the download dialog appear, but when I deploy my web application in *WebLogic*, after export click a blank page appear (the URL is .../export.com)

Comment: @Fra83 `jasper download dialog not appear` - About what dialog are you talking?

Comment: Download dialog [link](https://www.google.it/search?q=download+dialog&client=firefox-a&hs=ufK&rls=org.mozilla:it:official&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=5zpqUpqmF6WJ5ATS8YCQBQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1600&bih=702)